# Removing the margin or padding of Yii2 advanced application

Tags: css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Good day! I would like to remove the padding or margin of the Yii2 advanced app, I tried this code to the site.css but it did not work:

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;

}
```

Comment: try put this code in head *{margin:0;padding:0}??

Comment: Hello! I tried your suggestion but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Which padding and margin do you want remove?

Comment: I want to remove the margin and padding of main.php because I want the design of my app to be wide.

Comment: Before of all use reset css to try:
[Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)